# Playback video encrypted by Azure Media Service with the token

Tags: azure, aes, playback, azure-media-services, simple-web-token

I follow the step in the Azure Doc([Using AES-128 Dynamic Encryption and Key Delivery Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn783457.aspx)) and published a video by using the .NET SDK. However, I don't know how to use the token generated to play the encrypted content. In the other word, I don't know how to **request key with token**.

I read some related parts in the [HTTP Live Streaming draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-13](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-13) and it seems that the clients(I think it means the browsers which supports HLS) will automatically get the key and do the decryption, so how can I provide the token while it pull the key from the delivery server automatically?

Answer (score 0):

you can read following articles to see  token auth usage in azure media services and how to configure acs to issue tokens:

- [An End-to-End Prototype of AES Encryption with ACS Authentication and ACS Token Authorization](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/11/26/an-end-to-end-prototype-of-aes-encryption-with-acs-authentication-and-acs-token-authorization/)
- [How to configure ACS with Media Services key services](http://mingfeiy.com/acs-with-key-services)

If you want to issue SWT token yourself you can see sample implementation of SWT token [here](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Web/blob/master/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Web/Tokens/SwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs)

We are working on crafting more samples and i will update thread once we will release them.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. In the [An End-to-End Prototype ... ACS Token Authorization](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/11/26/an-end-to-end-prototype-of-aes-encryption-with-acs-authentication-and-acs-token-authorization/), at the very step, passing the token, the param of the flash var `AdaptiveStreamingPlugin_encryptionKeyToken=<%=authorizationToken %>` was set to the token, so it's possiable to playback the encrypted content, however if I'm using iOS or Android browser, where can I set this value?Or AMS doesn't support play the encrypted content by html5?

Comment: It's always best to include everything useful from a link in the post itself and provide the link as reference. You "answer" is borderline link-only, because it doesn't say mich itself. Please edit you answer.

Comment: bixiaopeng are you using some specific player or html video tag?

Comment: what do you mean for specific?I'm using the <video> tag in safari.

Comment: We don't have a solution for Safari playback yet (It's not that straightforward to insert token along with the HTTPs key request, which handles by the Safari when it receives KEY information in the second playlist). We are working with JWPlayer to make it available next month.

Comment: Thank you!That's the answer I want.

Answer (score 0):

Well,finally I find out the solution by ([fiddlr](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)), quite a great tool.

Just put your token in header with key authorization,just like

`authorization:Bearer=zone=az&Audience=urn%3atest&ExpiresOn=1418623783&Issuer=http%3a%2f%2fblog.tivo.com%2f&HMACSHA256=txxxxxxxxxxxxxxcF1GYUw%3d`

I'll attach some sample for how to generated a token later.