# How to make the HTML5 video requests use a certain header?

Tags: html, azure, azure-media-services

I posted a question [Playback video encrypted by Azure Media Service with the token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27419892/playback-video-encrypted-by-azure-media-service-with-the-token) to make out how the Azure key delivery server works, and It seems I should let the request with the token in header. However, on iOS device(and Android)which use the html5 to play the content, the request is occurred automatically. So **How can I customize the header of the request to the key delivery server**? I see a similar question posted here [Custom headers with HTML5 video requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777591/custom-headers-with-html5-video-requests) .But seems not resolved.

Comment: Did you manage to send custom headers for video requests?